# I accidentally installed the Wildstar Beta US client instead of the EU client. Can I fix this without reinstalling?

Tags: wildstar

As it says. I forgot to change the region from US to EU when installing the Wildstar beta client, and being from EU it would be helpful to play on EU servers (not to mention I added the EU beta key to my account, so I doubt I even would be able to connect to the US realms).

Is there a way to update my region without reinstalling the entire client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change region in the launcher even after you've installed the game. Click on the options button (looks like a gear in the top right corner), then select which region you would like to play in.

[image]

As a historical note, EU servers did not open until Open Beta started on May 8. Prior to that date, EU players played on NA servers. When EU servers were open, the developers copied all NA characters to the EU servers for the remainder of beta.